# Connected Sets after applying a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces, connectedness

Prove that if $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous function of metric spaces and $X$ is connected, then $f(X)$ is also connected.

I have tried to prove this by the contrapositive assuming $f(X) = A \cup B$ where the intersection of their closures is empty. Then I showed $X = f^{-1}(A) \cup f^{-1}(B)$ which might imply they are separated. Anyway, this is where I got confused because I don't know how to incorporate the part of $f$ being a continuous function.

Comment: You don’t just need any sets $A,B,$ you need them to be open sets to have $f(X)$ is not connected…

Comment: To deduce that $X$ is not connected, you need disjoint non-empty *open* subsets of $U,V\subset X$ such that $X=U\cup V.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Why do you think sets A and B have to be open?

Comment: You are assuming $f(X)$ is not connected. Look up the definition of connected again. All topological spaces with more than one point are not connected if we allow disjoint $A,B$ not necessarily open.

Comment: Hint:  $f$ is continuous on $X$ if and only if $f^{-1}(V)$ is closed in $X$ for every closed set $V$ in $Y$ (and equivalently for open sets in $Y$).

Answer (score 1):

We will prove a even stronger condition (where $X$ and $Y$ are arbitrary spaces and not just metric spaces)

Let $X$ be connected and $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be given. We prove that $Y$ is connected.
*Proof:* For the sake of contradiction assume that $f(X)$ is disconnected that is $f(X) = A \cup B$ where $A \cap B = \phi$. Now by definition of continuity, we know that $f^{-1}(A)$ is a open set of $X$ and $f^{-1}(B)$ is also a open set of $X$.

But $f^{-1}(A) \cup f^{-1}(B)$ constitute to a separation of $X$ which contradicts the fact that $X$ is connected hence $Y$ is connected

$□$

Now can we extend this to a if-and-only-if statement that is,

> Given $Y$ connected and a continuous map $f:X \rightarrow Y$, is $X$ connected?

I will leave this for you but if you get stuck just ping me here or ask a new question.